# Exchange 2010 PowerShell: Value.ToMB() Method Fails Remotely but Works Locally

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I am building a report of certain mailbox attributes from Exchange Server 2010 using PowerShell. The following code worked perfectly from my management workstation using a remote session.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited 
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
$Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value (Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize
}
```

However, when I added the **.Value.ToMb()** method to the TotalItemSize attribute, the script failed with the following error:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited 
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
$Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value ((Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMb())
}
```

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
>   At line:6 char:6 
>   +      $Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Val ... 
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
>   "[Mailbox Name Redacted]" value of type
>   "Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox" to
>   type 
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter".
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ParameterBindin...mationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-MailboxStatistics

And yet...the second block of code (converting the TotalItemSize value to MB) works perfectly when I run it locally on the Exchange server. Can anyone explain why this only fails remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you're missing the .Net types Exchange uses. PowerShell remoting perfomrs some serialization that makes some objects end up as "PsObject" instead of the full strongy typed object. The solution is to install the Exchange Management Console on your client computer, this will include the .Net types you need.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortunately our Exchange Server is in a resource forest and my management workstation is not. I've yet to find a way to install the exchange management tools on a machine that is not in the Exchange resource forest.

Comment: Gotcha. Although I haven't tried it yet, the EWS Managed api installer _might_ give you the same .net classes locally. No guarantees, tho. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951)

Comment: You don't need custom types or classes just to convert bytes to megabytes or whatnot... Just `$foo / 1mb`

Comment: That's not correct @RyanRies. Exchange uses it's own custom types, not regular ints. Believe me, I've tried :-)

Comment: Note, the EWS Managed API appears to require a 64-bit machine. I ran it first from my workstation and got a Windows Installer error stating that "This installation package is not suported by this processory type. Contact your product vendor."

Comment: Tested, and unfortunately failed at a slightly different point. In this test, the Value method worked on the Exchange server, but not on a remote management machine in a different forest.

Comment: SUCCESSFUL TEST: I installed Exchange management tools on 2 management servers in the Exchange resource forest and the .Value.ToMb() method worked on both. 

FINAL FAILED TEST: I tried using the Value.ToMb() method from a different server in the same forest, but without the Exchange management tools installed. The statement failed again, with the Value method returning a Null expression.

CONCLUSION: It looks like the EMT is required in order for the Value method to work properly against the TotalItemSize property of a mailbox statistic.

Comment: Footnote: based on the original answer, I finally tried running the command `Get-MailboxStatistics).TotalItemSize.Value.GetType().Fullname` and `Get-MailboxStatistics).TotalItemSize|Get-Member` on both sets of servers. With the EMC installed, this returns **Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize** as the type and lists Value as a method. Without the EMC installed, this returns the type as a **String** and no Value method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Then run the command set.

Comment: What does this parameter do?

Comment: This param: FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-MailboxStatistics lends itself to a forest view issue

Comment: That is a factor, but I don't think the actual problem. As noted in the answer/comments from Trondh, I am unable to install the required management tools because the management machine in question is not in the Exchange forest. In this case, the Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest command does not help. Thanks, though!